# Table Filtering with dropdown menu with jqGrid and php

Tags: php, jqgrid, drop-down-menu

I just wondering if i can create something similar to [this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/searching/search_toolbar/default.php) but with javascript code cause i don't wanna buy the whole Jgrid php library.

I talk about the 4th column (drop down menu filter).

I have just create the first grid as they say [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid)

Also i read some similar questions here but the most of them are based on ASP .net

If this can be achieved please give me some hints..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) together with the common [searching configuration](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config).  All the feature exists in the free open source version of jqGrid. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithCustomFormatterAndFilterToolbar1.htm). I hope it does what you need.